# checkboxcell event

Tags: events, gwt, checkbox, celltable

GWT 2.4
I have a `CheckBoxCell` in a `CellTable`. After checking/unchecking the checkbox, the change event fires twice. I can't figure out why.
Any help will be appreciated.

```java
private void createTable() {

    // Create a CellTable with a key provider.
    final CellTable<Contact> table = new CellTable<Contact>(KEY_PROVIDER);

    // Add a checkbox column
    final CheckboxCell cbCell = new CheckboxCell();
    Column<Contact, Boolean> cbColumn = new Column<Contact, Boolean>(cbCell) {
        @Override
        public Boolean getValue(Contact object) {
            System.out.println("method getValue() - " + object.id + " - " + object.checked);
            return object.checked;
        }
    };

    cbColumn.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<Fieldupdater.Contact, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void update(int index, Contact object, Boolean value) {
            System.out.println("method update() - " + object.id + " - " + value);
        }
    });

    table.addColumn(cbColumn);

    // Push the data into the widget.
    table.setRowData(CONTACTS);

    // Add it to the root panel.
    RootPanel.get("table1").add(table);
}
```

Comment: Do you use a FieldUpdater for this column? And why you always return null in getValue()?

Comment: I made this code small for testing, therefore return null. It's no production code.

Comment: I tried this with and without a FieldUpdater. The same result, the event fires twice.

Comment: Replace null with object.checked and see if you get two events like "true, true", or you get "true, false" (and vice versa).

Comment: I changed the code above.
I was  not interested in the return value of the method getValue in my code. I was looking why the method "getValue()" was called twice. I still do not understand.
The method "update" of the FieldUpdater is called once.
This is the output when I set the first checkbox checked

method getValue() - 1 - true
method getValue() - 1 - true
method update() - 1 - true

Comment: Forgotten to say Andrei, but thanks for your comments so far !!

Comment: I think this issue is related to the inner workings of CellTable. I saw this behavior with other cell types: when dataProvider is refreshed, getValue() is fired twice. I don't know the reason for it, but it does no harm as the value is not affected.

Comment: I take as it is. Thanks for your support.

Comment: You can post your own answer and close the question since you have found a solution.